# Trying to add 2 vectors of different sizes using a getter function

Tags: c++, class

So I'm trying to use this function to add two different vectors together, one of the vectors is a private member of my class, while the other in this case "RHS" is not a member of the class. So I am using a getter function and looping through it to generate a vector that I can work with. Here is the code that I am struggling with, I'm wondering if someone could take a look at it.

```
  Polynom Polynom::operator+(const Polynom& RHS)
  int i=0;
  int coeffres;
  vector<int> tempRHS;
  while(RHS.getCoeff(i,coeffres)){
     tempRHS.push_back(coeffres);
     i++;
  }

   int size;
  if(this->P.size()<tempRHS.size())
     size=tempRHS.size();
  else
     size=this->P.size();

  for(int i=size; i>0; i--)
  {
      tempRHS[i]=P[i]+tempRHS[i];
  }
```

and here is the getter function that I am looping through.

```
bool Polynom::getCoeff(int k, int& c) const
  {
     int value=P[P.size()-k];
     if (value == 0 || value<0)
     {
        return false;
     }
     else
     {
        c=value;
     return true;
     }

  }
```

Comment: This is a polynomial class that reads in polynomials and stores their coefficients in vectors. The power of each polynomial as I understand is the size of the vector -1. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Are the coefficients supposed to run from the highest power term to the lowest, or vice versa?

Comment: They are supposed to run from the highest power term to the lowest.

Comment: In other words the constant term is the `back()` of the vector.   So if the vectors are different sizes you need to skip some of the first elements of the longer one.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is take the longer vector and make a copy of it and then add the shorter vector to it. So yes we need to skip some of the first elements of the longer one.

Comment: _""RHS" is not a member of the class"_ true - it is another instance of your class, so you can still access all of its private members, like `RHS.P[i]`.

Comment: You need to post all of the `operator +` function.